# How to list collection first holders?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I'm developing an NFT collection on Solana using Metaplex Candy Machine V2 program. One of the requirements of the project is to be able to programmatically list the very first minters of each NFT (the wallet addresses which first minted and owned each NFT, before any secondary sales).

I tried using both candy machine's *get_all_owners_addresses* and Metaboss' *snapshot holders* commands, but both approaches only return the current holders.

Does anyone have any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is using [this website](https://pentacle.tools/nft-minters) providing the list of NFTs addresses that you want to get the original minter.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help. Perhaps do you know the logic to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, for example given a list of NFTs you can fetch the exactly first tx of his txs history (The tx that is more in the past), and there is the minter (The one who pay for every account creation and fees)

Comment: The webite @WrathionTBP linked also is open source, so you can just check the implementation here https://github.com/penta-fun/sol-nft-tools/

Answer (score -1):

You can also [holders.at](https://holders.at) to get NFT token holders of Ethereum and Polygon NFT collections